# How to enable google services for my app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I have a number of apps in my Google console: android connected to app engine. I need to use App-Engine and Google Cloud Messaging. The procedure asks me to choose `App name` and `android package name`. Then it says

```
Services will be added to your existing project in the Google Developers Console.
```

How does it know which project to add the service to? I can't seem to find where to tell it which project to use. For sure it keeps attaching them (apparently) to some default project as opposed to the correct project. I know that for a fact because it is not passing the correct projectId of my app-engine backend to the `google-services.json`. I am not sure I should manually edit the file. So any ideas how to generate the file the correct way?

I am referring to the **Configuration File**

Presently I am following https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Answer (score 2):

App Name and package name fields are editable fields when you're trying to create a configuration file as described [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)

[image]

You can choose an existing project that you created in your [google developer console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?osid=1&passive=true&continue=https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard) from the dropdown or enter a new name. If no app with that name exists in your google developer console, a project with that name will be created in google developer console. Configuration file generated will have `project_id`, `project_number`for this project and when you will use this json file in the android app, it will use them to connect to the correct project.